# Why do I get the first and last Posts from a WP_query call repeated in my results?

Tags: arrays, wordpress, while-loop

I'm using a WP_Query call to populate a slider with the thumbnails of all of my 'added' Custom Post Types, but the first and last posts from the results both appear three times in the loop.

I've tried echoing an int within the loop to identify where it's going wrong, and the int doesn't appear in every loop either, so these posts are somehow being called separately. I've been over my code repeatedly but cannot figure out where this is going wrong.

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'added', // enter your custom post type
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'orderby'        => 'title',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
);

$added_query = new WP_Query( $args );

$i = 0;

// if( $added_query->have_posts() ):
    echo '<div id="slider" class="add-something container slideshow-container slider fadeInUp">';
        echo '<h2>FOR OVER 20 YEARS WE&apos;VE ADDED SOMETHING TO</h2>';
        echo '<div class="slider-wrapper">';
            echo '<div id="slides" class="slides">';

            while( $added_query->have_posts() ):
                $added_query->the_post();
                echo $i;
                // global $post;
                ?>
                <div class="added-link slide" style="width:150px;">
                    <div class="added-logo">
                        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(),'medium'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                wp_reset_postdata();
                $i++;
            endwhile;

            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
// endif;
?>
```

This code results in:
[Duplicate posts interrupting the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJXqV.png)

There are no other WP_Query calls elsewhere in the page template. How can I get rid of these extra slides if they aren't produced by the `while` loop? And why are they interrupting my loop like this?

Edit: Following @Aurel 's advice I've tried adding some styling to the "added-logo" class, and [it gets applied to all of the images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsTd4.png).

Comment: I was testing out your loop and everything looked fine and wasn't repeating on my end. I'm wondering if this is something your slider is doing. What is the JavaScript slider library you are using?

Comment: @ConnorSmyth I'm not using a JS library, just some vanilla JS I modified from a CodePen I found. I'll give it a look over though, see if it might be interfering somehow.

Comment: @ConnorSmyth Your comment got me on the right track: the JS had some duplicating code in it:
    items.appendChild(cloneFirst);
    items.insertBefore(cloneLast, firstSlide);

Answer (score 0):

0 and 3 values seems to have a bigger image than 1 and 2. Can you add a style on added-logo CSS class ? or like :

```
<div class="added-logo" style="border:solid 1px #ff0000;">
                        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(),'medium'); ?>
                    </div>
```

for debugging purpose only and post the image ? thanks